# How to update text with canvas.drawText in OnDraw? Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a custom view for my app and I'm trying to update a text everytime OnDraw is called.

(some of) my code lookes like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.e(TAG,"onDraw");
    drawBackground(canvas);

    float scale = (float) getWidth();       
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);


    drawTitle(canvas);
    drawHand(canvas);


    canvas.restore();

    if (handNeedsToMove()) {
        moveHand();
    }
}

private void drawTitle(Canvas canvas) {

    String title = getTitle();
    Log.i("drawtitle",title);

    titlePaint = new Paint();
    titlePaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    titlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    titlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    titlePaint.setTextSize(0.05f);
    titlePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);

    canvas.drawText(title, 0.45f, 0.95f, titlePaint);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);

    regenerateBackground();
}
private void regenerateBackground() {
    if (background != null) {
        background.recycle();
    }

        //Some stuff here

    drawInstruments(backgroundCanvas);
    drawTitle(backgroundCanvas);

}
```

The text get updated when it's called by regenerateBackground but stays the same on OnDraw. Why? How to fix? Maby there is a better way than using canvas.drawText? I am making a speedometer and I just want to print the value of which the "needle" is pointing at...

edit: full code

public final class Dashboard extends View {

```
private static final String TAG = Dashboard.class.getSimpleName();

// drawing tools
private Paint dashPaint;
private static Bitmap dash;
private Matrix dashMatrix;
private float dashScalex;   
private float dashScaley;   

private Paint handPaint;
private Path handPath;
private Paint handScrewPaint;

private Paint backgroundPaint; 
// end drawing tools

private Bitmap background; // holds the cached static part


private Paint titlePaint;
private Path titlePath;

// scale configuration
private static final int totalNicks = 100;
private static final float degreesPerNick = 360.0f / totalNicks;    
private static final int centerDegree = 40; // the one in the top center (12 o'clock)
private static final int minDegrees = -30;
private static final int maxDegrees = 110;

// hand dynamics -- all are angular expressed in F degrees
private boolean handInitialized = true;
private float handPosition = centerDegree;
private float handTarget = centerDegree;
private float handVelocity = 0.0f;
private float handAcceleration = 0.0f;
private long lastHandMoveTime = -1L;

private static  float circlePosx = 0.5f;
private static  float circlePosy = 0.36f;
private static float circleRadius = 0.1f;

public Dashboard(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Dashboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public Dashboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
    Parcelable superState = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

    handInitialized = bundle.getBoolean("handInitialized");
    handPosition = bundle.getFloat("handPosition");
    handTarget = bundle.getFloat("handTarget");
    handVelocity = bundle.getFloat("handVelocity");
    handAcceleration = bundle.getFloat("handAcceleration");
    lastHandMoveTime = bundle.getLong("lastHandMoveTime");
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    state.putParcelable("superState", superState);
    state.putBoolean("handInitialized", handInitialized);
    state.putFloat("handPosition", handPosition);
    state.putFloat("handTarget", handTarget);
    state.putFloat("handVelocity", handVelocity);
    state.putFloat("handAcceleration", handAcceleration);
    state.putLong("lastHandMoveTime", lastHandMoveTime);
    return state;
}

public static float[] getCircle(){      
    float[] circle = {circlePosx,circlePosy,circleRadius};
    return circle;  
}

public static int[] getCanvasSize(){
    int[] size = {dash.getWidth(),dash.getHeight()};
    return size;
}

private void init() {
    initDrawingTools();
}

private void initDrawingTools() {

    /******/
    dashPaint = new Paint();
    dashPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    dash = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.dashboard);
    dashMatrix = new Matrix();


    dashScaley = 1f/dash.getHeight();// * 0.3f;;
    dashScalex = 1f/dash.getWidth();
    dashMatrix.setScale(dashScalex, dashScaley);    

    Log.i("dash width", "= "+dash.getWidth()+" - "+getWidth());
    Log.i("dash height", "= "+dash.getHeight());
    Log.i("dash scale x ", "= "+1f/dash.getHeight());
    Log.i("dash scale y ", "= "+dashScaley);

    /******/

    handPaint = new Paint();
    handPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);     
    handPaint.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -0.005f, -0.005f, 0x7f000000);
    handPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);   



    handPath = new Path();
    handPath.moveTo(circlePosx-0.01f, circlePosy+0.06f);

    handPath.lineTo(circlePosx, circlePosy - 0.16f);
    handPath.lineTo(circlePosx+0.01f, circlePosy + 0.06f);
    handPath.addCircle(circlePosx, circlePosy, 0.025f, Path.Direction.CW);

    handScrewPaint = new Paint();
    handScrewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    handScrewPaint.setColor(0xf0000021);
    handScrewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    titlePaint = new Paint();
    titlePaint.setColor(0xffffffff);
    titlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    titlePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    titlePaint.setTextSize(0.05f);
    titlePaint.setTextScaleX(0.8f);


    titlePath = new Path();
    titlePath.moveTo(0.5f, 0.8f);
    titlePath.lineTo(0.6f, 0.8f);
    //titlePath = new Path();
    //titlePath.addArc(new RectF(0.24f, 0.24f, 0.76f, 0.76f), -180.0f, -180.0f);        

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
    Log.d(TAG, "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
    int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);


    setMeasuredDimension(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

    //int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
    //setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
}

private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) {
    if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        return size;
    } else { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        return getPreferredSize();
    } 
}

// in case there is no size specified
private int getPreferredSize() {
    return 600;
}



private int nickToDegree(int nick) {
    int rawDegree = ((nick < totalNicks / 2) ? nick : (nick - totalNicks)) * 2;
    int shiftedDegree = rawDegree + centerDegree;
    return shiftedDegree;
}

private float degreeToAngle(float degree) {
    return (degree - centerDegree) / 2.0f * degreesPerNick;
}

private void drawInstruments(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

    canvas.translate(0.5f - dash.getWidth() * dashScalex / 2.0f, 
                     0.5f - dash.getHeight() * dashScaley / 2.0f);

    //canvas.drawBitmap(dash, 0, 0, dashPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(dash, dashMatrix, dashPaint);
    canvas.restore();           
}

private void drawHand(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.e(TAG, "drawHand");
    if (handInitialized) {

        float handAngle = degreeToAngle(handPosition);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(handAngle, circlePosx, circlePosy);
        canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.36f, 0.01f, handScrewPaint);

    }
}
private String getTitle(){
    return String.valueOf(handPosition);
}
private void drawTitle(Canvas canvas) {

    String title = getTitle();
    //canvas.drawTextOnPath(title, titlePath, 0.0f,0.0f, titlePaint);   
    //canvas.drawPaint(titlePaint);

    Log.i("drawtitle",title);

    canvas.drawText(title, 0.45f, 0.95f, titlePaint);
    //invalidate();
}   


private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    if (background == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Background not created");
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, backgroundPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.e(TAG,"onDraw");
    drawBackground(canvas);

    float scale = (float) getWidth();       
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);


    drawTitle(canvas);
    drawHand(canvas);


    canvas.restore();

    if (handNeedsToMove()) {
        moveHand();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);

    regenerateBackground();
}

private void regenerateBackground() {
    // free the old bitmap
    if (background != null) {
        background.recycle();
    }


    Log.e("Width="+getWidth(), "Height="+getHeight());
    background = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(background);

    float scalex = (float) getWidth();  
    float scaley = (float) getHeight(); 
    backgroundCanvas.scale(scalex, scaley);

    drawInstruments(backgroundCanvas);

}

private boolean handNeedsToMove() {
    return Math.abs(handPosition - handTarget) > 0.01f;
}

private void moveHand() {
    Log.e(TAG, "moveHand!!");
    if (! handNeedsToMove()) {
        return;
    }

    if (lastHandMoveTime != -1L) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float delta = (currentTime - lastHandMoveTime) / 1000.0f;

        float direction = Math.signum(handVelocity);
        if (Math.abs(handVelocity) < 90.0f) {
            handAcceleration = 5.0f * (handTarget - handPosition);
        } else {
            handAcceleration = 0.0f;
        }
        handPosition += handVelocity * delta;
        handVelocity += handAcceleration * delta;
        if ((handTarget - handPosition) * direction < 0.01f * direction) {
            handPosition = handTarget;
            handVelocity = 0.0f;
            handAcceleration = 0.0f;
            lastHandMoveTime = -1L;
        } else {
            lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();              
        }
        invalidate();
    } else {
        lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        moveHand();
    }
}


private float getRelativeTemperaturePosition() {
    if (handPosition < centerDegree) {
        return - (centerDegree - handPosition) / (float) (centerDegree - minDegrees);
    } else {
        return (handPosition - centerDegree) / (float) (maxDegrees - centerDegree);
    }
}

public void setHandTarget(float temperature) {
    Log.e(TAG, "setHandTarget!");
    if (temperature < minDegrees) {
        temperature = minDegrees;
    } else if (temperature > maxDegrees) {
        temperature = maxDegrees;
    }
    handTarget = temperature;
    Log.e(TAG, "handTarget="+handTarget);
    handInitialized = true;
    invalidate();
}

public float getHandTarget(){
    return handTarget;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call to `drawTitle()` from `regenerateBackground()` and call invalidate inside your setTitle() method.

Comment: That is just making the view to regenerate all the time (and without printing anything). I have a call to invalidate inside of drawHand..

Comment: My guess is that the title is the text you want to update regularly. By calling invalidate you trigger an onDraw. And since you need to redraw if the title changes, setTitle() is the place to call invalidate. Also since the title changes often it should not be part of the background image. Thats why you should remove it from regenerateBackrgound(). If you call invalidate in drawHand() you created an endless cycle of onDraw->invalidate

Comment: That is correct, but I need to update the canvas in drawHand() aswell. Won't I need the invalidate there? Edit: Also, the onDraw() is called when it's needed aldry (by drawHand()). So the method drawTitle() is called but for some reason it's not changed.

Comment: Its impossible to help you further without you showing us more of your code. My suggestion is: remove invalidate from drawHand and put it into the functions which change the state of your custom view (likely you setSpeed or setXX and possibly moveHand() function). Additionally you should not draw the title onto the background since it changes often

Comment: Ok. I'm new to this and I don't really understand what you mean so I'll just post the whole code for you :)

Comment: code looks good. You call setHandTarget() and your view will automatically redraw itself until the hand reaches the target. Since drawTitle uses the current handPosition everything should work as expected. This is more a debugging task rather than a good SO-question- So if you still have problems. Debug your code, narrow down the problem and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I've staired at this code for a day now without finding any sulution :P. But I'll give it another try. Thanks for your help!